# Pytest capture not working - caplog and capsys are empty

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to create unit tests for a logger, but - even though the events are logged - the `caplog` and `capsys` remain empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out that my logger had property `propagate` set to `False`. As a result, the events were not forwarded to `LogCaptureHandler` added by pytest to the root logger.

Both `caplog` and `capsys` depend on `LogCaptureHandler` receiving the propagated events.

[image: LogCaptureHandler]

Comment: Having the same trouble https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052171/empty-messages-in-caplog-how-to-troubleshoot , however propagate is True

Comment: What IDE did you use to get such a useful attribute/state inspector?

Comment: @Stew It's **PyCharm**, `Variables` pane in debugging mode I think.