# Empty messages in caplog when logs emmited in a different process

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am running the test with log_cli=true.
The script:

```py
import logging
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger("leapp.actors.quagga_report")


class ActorContext:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logger

    def run(self):
        self.log.debug("Some msg")


current_actor_context = ActorContext()


def test_caplog_fails(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG, logger="leapp.actors.quagga_report"):
        p = Process(target=current_actor_context.run)
        p.start()
        p.join()
    assert "Some msg" in caplog.text


def test_caplog_passes(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG, logger="leapp.actors.quagga_report"):
        current_actor_context.run()
    assert "Some msg" in caplog.text
```

pytest log_cli shows the log message in both tests,
however, the caplog sees the messages only for the second test.

First test fails with the following traceback:

```
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
| 13:39:20 | 40212 | leapp.actors.quagga_report | DEBUG | test_logger_caplog_fails.py | Some msg
FAILED
tests/test_logger_caplog_fails.py:20 (test_caplog_fails)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azhukov/Dropbox/code/lighting_talks/asyncio_subprocess_shells/tests/test_logger_caplog_fails.py", line 26, in test_caplog_fails
    assert "Some msg" in caplog.text
AssertionError: assert 'Some msg' in ''
 +  where '' = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x7fb8a87f2370>.text
```

I was looking to a similar question [Pytest capture not working - caplog and capsys are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702794/pytest-capture-not-working-caplog-and-capsys-are-empty) , however in my case the property `propagate=True`

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? The issue is not reproducible per se.

Comment: Fixed. trying to do a minimal reproducible example now... The problem is that the library is quite complex and it is nt the easy task to find how the logger built.... I'll ping you @hoefling

Comment: I would probably search at the logger configuration, extract that into a standalone example and check whether the issue is reproducible with that...

Comment: @hoefling ok, so I found the problem. Please check the description one more time. Thanks

Comment: @hoefling oh, I see you were on it already https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3037 :)))

Comment: Yep, I remember having to jump through some hoops trying to access the logs - I think I had to set up a TCP server and monkeypatch logging config to use socket handlers. I see there's a solution listed there now, try it out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by @hoefling and still the will to use caplog, there is a solution. The idea is to create a fixture, which takes the queue from the QueueHandler handler and reemits the logs in the main process, which is capturable by the caplog

```py
import logging
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager
from logging import handlers
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

import pytest

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ActorContext:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logger

    def run(self):
        self.log.debug("Some msg")


current_actor_context = ActorContext()


@pytest.fixture()
def caplog_workaround():
    @contextmanager
    def ctx():
        logger_queue = Queue()
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.addHandler(handlers.QueueHandler(logger_queue))
        yield
        while not logger_queue.empty():
            log_record: logging.LogRecord = logger_queue.get()
            logger._log(
                level=log_record.levelno,
                msg=log_record.message,
                args=log_record.args,
                exc_info=log_record.exc_info,
            )

    return ctx


def test_caplog_already_not_fails(caplog, caplog_workaround):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG, logger="leapp.actors.quagga_report"):
        with caplog_workaround():
            p = Process(target=current_actor_context.run)
            p.start()
            p.join()
    assert "Some msg" in caplog.text


def test_caplog_passes(caplog, capsys):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG, logger="leapp.actors.quagga_report"):
        current_actor_context.run()
    assert "Some msg" in caplog.text
```

Comment: @hoefling please review:)

Comment: This hack almost worked fine for me. Maybe, isn't it better to add `logger.removeHandler()` above `while` block to prevent infinite log loop? (I encountered.)

Comment: @YukihikoShinoda I’ll take a look. Thx for improving the solution